# Android Lock Screen Controls in <= 4.1.2

Tags: android, widget, locking, screen, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I know Jelly Bean 4.2 added the ability to create lock screen widgets, but I also noticed that certain apps (such as Spotify) have added lock screen play/pause/stop/etc controls even for my 4.1.2 phone. I can't for the life of me figure out how they did it, though. How can I do something like this in my apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html

> The new RemoteControlClient allows media players to enable playback controls from remote control clients such as the device lock screen. Media players can also expose information about the media currently playing for display on the remote control, such as track information and album art.

and a few more paragraphs on the subject.

You register a `RemoteControlClient` via [`registerRemoteControlClient()` on `AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerRemoteControlClient%28android.media.RemoteControlClient%29).

Comment: I see, so this is only available for audio player types of applications, not for general app controls? I have a timer-type app that I'd love to add the option to have pause/resume buttons from the lockscreen, but it sounds like this isn't possible with 4.1.2, correct?

Comment: @joshwoodward: "not for general app controls?" -- that's what it's designed for. "I'd love to add the option to have pause/resume buttons from the lockscreen" -- in theory, you could use media pause/resume affect your timer, though the API certainly isn't aimed for that, and I have no idea what sorts of problems you'd run into.

Answer (score 1):

You can still register the MediaButtonIntent and use the RemoteControlClient API as mentioned by CommonsWare. You're app needs to gain the audio focus though then you can have you're own broadcast receiver that reacts to the buttons as you like. The API to mimic the media intent has become public in kitKat